# Error getting Block in controller Magento 2: Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern']

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I'm trying to get block in my frontend controller like this:

```
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$breadcrumbs = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
```

this is my XML file layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\View\Index" name="promotion.view.categories" template="Vendor_Module::view/index.phtml">
                <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="promotion.view.subcategories.wrapper"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

i always get an error like this:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
```

Comment: please add your .xml file

Comment: @MohitPatel just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the first backward slash from the class name.

It has to be `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` instead of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`.

Answer (score 0):

First go to your layout file and chnage this

your file code :-

```
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="promotion.view.subcategories.wrapper"/>
```

new code 
**chnage to**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="promotion.view.subcategories.wrapper"/>
```

After run `php bin/magento c:f` and check

Any query let me know

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @jojo please check my answer helpful or not ???

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was caused by developer mode which was enabled for magento.
I changed that to default mode again and everything worked fine.

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set default